# Python string 'in' operator implementation algorithm and time complexity

Tags: python, string, algorithm, cpython

I am thinking of how the `in` operator implement, for instance

```
>>> s1 = 'abcdef'
>>> s2 = 'bcd'
>>> s2 in s1
True
```

In CPython, which algorithm is used to implement the string match, and what is the time complexity? Is there any official document or wiki about this?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why KMP wasn't used for this implementation?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's a combination of [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) and [Horspool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore-Horspool_algorithm).

You can view the C code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h):

> Fast search/count implementation, based on a mix between Boyer-Moore and Horspool, with a few more bells and whistles on the top. For some more background, see: https://web.archive.org/web/20201107074620/http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm.

From the link above:

> When designing the new algorithm, I used the following constraints:
>
> - should be faster than the current brute-force algorithm for all test cases (based on real-life code), including Jim Hugunin’s worst-case test
> - small setup overhead; no dynamic allocation in the fast path (O(m) for speed, O(1) for storage)
> - sublinear search behaviour in good cases (O(n/m))
> - no worse than the current algorithm in worst case (O(nm))
> - should work well for both 8-bit strings and 16-bit or 32-bit Unicode strings (no O(σ) dependencies)
> - many real-life searches should be good, very few should be worst case
> - reasonably simple implementation

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Based on this article, http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm, the time complexity is sublinear , that is better than KMP algorithm.

Comment: @mitchelllc In the *best cases* it can be sublinear.

Comment: @arshajiii yes, that's what I want. Thanks again!

Comment: @arshajiii One more question, do you know when the good cases happen? I cannot figure out that. thx

Comment: @mitchelllc probably when there aren't frequent 'false partial matches' e.g. 'bcdefg' and searching for 'fg' rather than looking for 'aab' in 'aaaacaaab'