# Repeated String Match association with Boyer Moore Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, search, data-structures, substring

Posting this question after looking around different blogs/SO questions and still not finding an answer

I'm trying to wrap my head around a solution/algorithm used from a leetcode contest.

Here is the question:

> Given two strings A and B, find the minimum number of times A has to be repeated such that B is a substring of it. If no such solution, return -1.
>
> For example, with A = "abcd" and B = "cdabcdab".
>
> Return 3, because by repeating A three times (“abcdabcdabcd”), B is a substring of it; and B is not a substring of A repeated two times ("abcdabcd").

I know that rolling hash approach is the preferred way to go but I decided to start with the Boyer Moore approach.

After doing some research I learned that the following code used Boyer Moore Algorithm behind the scenes. Here is the code:

```
def repeatedStringMatch(self, A, B):
    """
    :type A: str
    :type B: str
    :rtype: int
    """
    m = math.ceil(len(B)/len(A))
    if B in A * m:
        return m
    elif B in A * (m + 1):
        return m + 1
    else:
        return -1
```

Based on my understanding of the algorithm I'm not convinced how the above solution might be using BM approach.

I'm specifically not clear what this line

```
  m = math.ceil(len(B)/len(A))
```

does and why we have to find m in this fashion. Could anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The purpose of `m` looks to be a multiplier on the string`A` so that `A` is greater than or equal to the length of `B`. I'm not so familiar with Boyer Moore, but doing `B in A` is definitely not BM since that preforms a naive search.

Comment: @Miket25, the algorithm behind `B in A` appears to be [boyer-moore in cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h)

Comment: @HaleemurAli Ah so it seems to be a mix of Boyer-Moore and Horspool from your link and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139660/python-string-in-operator-implementation-algorithm-and-time-complexity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smaller string must be repeated *at least* `m` times for the larger string to be contained within.

The minimum value that `m` can assume is the smallest integer greater than the ratio of the lengths of two strings (larger / smaller), because, to contain a substring of length `l`, a string must have at least length `l`.

Using the example you shared.

```
A = "abcd"
B = "cdabcdab"
m0 = len(B) / len(A)
# m0 == 2.0
m = math.ceil(m0)
# m = 2
```

However, `"cdabcdab"` is not contained in `"abcdabcd"`. But, if we repeat "abcd" 1 more time, we find that `"cdabcdab"` is then a substring. Repeating "abcd" further doesn't change whether it may be found as a substring or not. So, it is only necessary to check containment for `m` & `(m+1)` repetitions.

The python code you shared does not implement any searching algorithm, it just uses whatever searching algorithm is implemented for use with `in`. The specific algorithm might be implementation dependent, however there is a high likelihood for it to be boyer-moore or a variation of, as it is popular & efficient.

edit:

the algorithm behind `B in A` appears to be [boyer-moore in cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h)

Comment: ah that makes perfect sense - thank you for the explanation :)