# Python - How to search a large string with no spaces, to see if a value exists

Tags: python

I have a large string full of byte code so there is no spaces, I am trying to search for a specific part of that code.

For example;

`byte_code = 'ergewyegt6t4738t8347tygfhfh47tg4378t58437t485t454gyfofby3gyfg34t5t6435t3465tg3465t4'`

The value I am looking for is 'fhfh47tg'.

I have tried the .find String method but did not have much luck. 
As mentioned before, the string has no spaces.

I'd expect the output to be true once it has found the pattern within the string.

Comment: `'fhfh47tg' in byte_code` ?

Comment: Please include the code you have tried. str.find should work fine, but it returns `-1` if there's no match. If you don't care where in the string your pattern is found, use `in` operator instead.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: That will return False only if the substring is found at the beginning of the search string (index 0, which is a falsy value). A non-match will return `-1` which is truthy. Instead you could use `print(byte_code.find('fhfh47tg') != -1)`

Comment: @HåkenLid Didn't thought about that :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `in` (`__contains__`) test for substring existence:

```
if 'fhfh47tg' in byte_code:
    print('Match found')
```

You can also look at methods like `str.find`, `str.index` FWIW.

Comment: In cpython (and I assume most other runtimes), the implementation of `str.__contains__()` is independent of regular string iteration. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139681/1977847

Comment: Always better than regex.

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.search` is one option:

```
if re.search(r'fhfh47tg', byte_code):
    print("MATCH")
else:
    print("NO MATCH")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do

```
if 'fhfh47tg' in byte_code:
    return True
```

or

```
return 'fhfh47tg' in byte_code
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

```
byte_code = 'ergewyegt6t4738t8347tygfhfh47tg4378t58437t485t454gyfofby3gyfg34t5t6435t3465tg3465t4'
    
if 'fhfh47tg' in byte_code:
    print("Value is present.")
```

(you can change the output as per your liking.)

Peace out.