# Various search algorithms and performance for full text matching

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, search, full-text-search

Let's say I have the following string:

```
/Volumes/01/LG_SICARIO_ES419SUB_16X9_240_2398_DIGITAL_FINAL.itt
```

How would I determine the fastest way to search this string for a match given input terms `['sicario', '419']`

For example, the most basic version would be:

1) String contains:

```
s = '/Volumes/01/LG_SICARIO_ES419SUB_16X9_240_2398_DIGITAL_FINAL.itt'
terms = ['sicario', '419']
has_match = all([term.lower() in s.lower() for term in terms])
```

2) Regex

```
has_match = all([re.compile(term, re.I).search(s) for term in terms])
```

Other possible options would be:

- Rabin-Karp
- Boyer-Moore
- And other [string-searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm)

What would be the time complexity of the various algorithms?

---

Here is what I got for timing `regex` vs `str() in`:

```
 import timeit

 # Case insensitive
setup =  's="/Volumes/01/LG_SICARIO_ES419SUB_16X9_240_2398_DIGITAL_FINAL.itt"; terms = ["sicario", "419"]'
print min(timeit.Timer('all([term in s.lower() for term in terms])', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000))
0.00134181976318

# Case sensitive
setup =  's="/Volumes/01/LG_SICARIO_ES419SUB_16X9_240_2398_DIGITAL_FINAL.itt"; terms = ["sicario", "419"]'
print min(timeit.Timer('all([term in s for term in terms])', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000))
0.000231027603149


# Regex case insensitive
setup =  'import re; s="/Volumes/01/LG_SICARIO_ES419SUB_16X9_240_2398_DIGITAL_FINAL.itt"; compiled_terms = [re.compile("sicario", re.I), re.compile("419", re.I)]'
print min(timeit.Timer('all([compiled_term.search(s) for compiled_term in compiled_terms])', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000))
0.00111889839172


# Regex case sensitive
setup =  'import re; s="/Volumes/01/LG_SICARIO_ES419SUB_16X9_240_2398_DIGITAL_FINAL.itt"; compiled_terms = [re.compile("sicario"), re.compile("419")]'
print min(timeit.Timer('all([compiled_term.search(s) for compiled_term in compiled_terms])', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000))
0.000588893890381
```

It's pretty close, though case-sensitive string searches perform about 2x better than regex (at least on this input data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your basic version is the fastest ([a combination of Boyer-Moore and Horspoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139660/python-string-in-operator-implementation-algorithm-and-time-complexity)) available (sublinear search behaviour in good cases (O(n/m)), I will add small changes to your basic version:

```
def test():
    lower_s = s .lower()
    return all([term in lower_s for term in terms])
```

Comment: @ruso -- could you please explain why it would be fastest though? Basically I'm trying to learn a bit more about the algorithms, etc. behind the scenes and why one approach would be better than another.

Comment: also you may have a look over the basic classification of search algorithms/Single-pattern algorithms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm

Comment: and I think is the fastest because it is implemented in c