# Python specific find in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn python with learning by doing way, but i have a problem with my code. Trying to do a code, where you input IP and code will check, if IP is in the ips.txt file, but when i add for example "192.168.0.10" and in file already is "192.168.0.100" then it will show, that "192.168.0.10" is in txt file, because "10" is part of the "100" number.

The same example is "dog" and "dogs", "dog" is basically inside "dogs", so it will tell that dog is in file...

Can you help me with it? Thanks

````
IPs = IPs.read()
IP = input("Check IP: ")
if IP in IPs:
    print("IP is in the list.")
else:
    print("IP is not in the list.") ```
````

Comment: `IPs` is a _string_. `IP in IPs` will check if `IP` is a _substring_ of the string `IPs`, so this code works correctly. Are you sure you want `IPs` to be _a single string_, and not, say, a _list_ of strings?

Comment: What is the content of the ips.txt-file? Are the IP-adresses separated by newlines, spaces or something else?

Comment: @shmulvad in file are IPS, each IP is on the new line

Comment: @ForceBru where i can find a better solution, or your list of strings recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPs.read()` produces a string. This means when you perform `IP in IPs`, it's checking whether the string `IP` is a substring of `IPs` (it performs a [`substring search`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139660/python-string-in-operator-implementation-algorithm-and-time-complexity)). In your situation, notice `"" in IPs`, `"1" in IPs` and `".1" in IPs` will all evaluate to `True`.

What you want is `IPs` to be a list of strings, which can achieved via:

```
IPs = IPs.read().splitlines()
```

This reads the input and splits the string by newlines, so if the text files contains:

```
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.9
192.168.0.7
```

IPs will be:

```
["192.168.0.10", "192.168.0.9", "192.168.0.7"]
```

So now, when you do `IP in IPs` it will [`linear search`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-search/) for the value `IP` in `IPs`. Linear search takes `O(n)` time, where `n` is the length of the list. If the order of `IPs` doesn't matter and you're making a lot of lookups, I recommend turning the list into a set via `IPs = set(IPs.read().splitlines())`. This way, when you do `IP in IPs`, the time to lookup is constant, no matter the size of the list (aka program go zoom).

Comment: Damn, thats it! Thanks a lot dude!